# How to find the genus of curve $x^2-\cos(y)=c$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, plane-curves

$x^2-\cos(y)=c$ is not an algebraic curve, and its genus may depend on the constant $c$, how to find them? In general, do we have any algorithms for transcendental curves?

Comment: Do we have a definition of genus for such curves?

Comment: @Lubin I would assume the OP means the genus as a Riemann surface in $\mathbb C^2$.

Answer (score 2):

This curve $X$ is the Riemann surface of the multivalued function $y \mapsto \sqrt{c + \cos(y)}$. The function $\cos(y) $ is surjective, hence there are infinitely many branch points, given by $(x,y)= (0,y_0)$ where $y_0 \in \mathbb C$ is a solution of $\cos(y_0) = -c$.

It follows that the genus of the curve is infinite, independently of $c$, because for each pair of branch points $(y_0,y_1)$ you get a new non-trivial cycle. If you take the $y_i$'s all disjoint they will be independent in homology.

Comment: For $c\ne \pm 1$ it is a Riemann surface with infinitely many holes, for $c=\pm 1$ it is the union of two Riemann surfaces isomorphic to $\Bbb{C}$ intersecting at the $y_0+\pi \Bbb{Z}$

Comment: $\sqrt{1+\cos(y)}$ is entire

Comment: @Nicolas Hemelsoet, thank you very much for clarifying the definition, but I still do not understand too much. I found a similar curve on arxiv (https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.07065), where authors give an example with $-\cosh(x)$, instead of $\cos(x)$. As they demonstrate (from eq. 2.10 to eq. 2.16), the curve $y^2=1-\cosh(x)$ is a torus, thus it has $g=1$. However, according to your treatment, I found the same answer for $\cosh(x)$, i.e. the genus is infinite. What's the problem here?

Comment: The reason that leads me to suspect that its genus depends on $c$ is the structure of the curve on real plane x-y, $c=\pm$ are two special points.

Comment: @user142288 : My answer didn't consider the singular points that occur for $c = \pm{-1}$ indeed. About the paper you mentioned, I don't understand it, because the same analysis should give the same answer for (almost) all $c$. If you find the solution, please consider write it here ! I would be interested.

Comment: @user142288 Again for $c=\pm 1$ then $f(y)=\sqrt{c+\cosh(y)}$ is entire and your set is $\{ (f(y),y),y\in \Bbb{C}\}\cup \{ (-f(y),y),y\in \Bbb{C}\}$ is not a Riemann surface, it is the union of two Riemann surfaces isomorphic to $\Bbb{C}$, of genus $0$, and intersecting at the $(0,i\pi (n+1/2))$.

Comment: Now if you meant $(x,y)\in \Bbb{R}^2$ then it is a bit different.